# MySQL server on Amazon RDS not reachable from only one host

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have multiple hosts that connect with a database on an Amazon RDS server. The normal webservers have no trouble connecting with the database, but today I discovered that my development server couldn't connect.

The error I get is

> 'ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'endpoint.blabla.rds.amazonaws.com' (113)'

Trying to connect via my home laptop gives no problems. It's only the devserver.

When I initiate a connection from the devserver via nc, it gives 'No route to host'. As far as I know, I didn't change anything on the devserver. The databaseserver however has been resized last Thursday, but I'm not sure when the problems have started. I know that it still worked two weeks ago, that's all.

Anyone any experienced this before with Amazon RDS? I really don't know where to look at the moment. The VPC security groups haven't changed, and other servers with the same security groups on the same VPC have no trouble connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is solved after a couple of hours searching. There was a route in my route table that caused the trouble. I have no idea how it got there, but it is solved now, I can reach the server again. :)